# Durandal.js 2.0 Set document title within activate method

Tags: durandal

In my shell, I have set up my routes like so:

```
router.map([
            { route: '', title: 'Search', moduleId: 'viewmodels/search/search' },
            { route: 'location/:paramX/:paramY', title: 'Location', moduleId: 'viewmodels/location/location' }
        ]).buildNavigationModel();
```

I have an activate method like so:

```
activate: function(paramX, paramY) {
    // TODO: set document title
    // TODO: do something with input params    
}
```

For the location page, the document title is set to the Location | [Name of my app].  I would like to change this to be made up from the params taken in the activate method (paramX, paramY) on my activate method for the location page.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve this by overriding the default behaviour of the process of the router to set the title.

The title is always set after the navigation is complete so the activate method of your viewmodel has been called before. The current implementation in Durandal 2.0 is:

```
   router.updateDocumentTitle = function(instance, instruction) {
        if (instruction.config.title) {
            if (app.title) {
                document.title = instruction.config.title + " | " + app.title;
            } else {
                document.title = instruction.config.title;
            }
        } else if (app.title) {
            document.title = app.title;
        }
    };
```

This is called in the method `completeNavigation` in the `router.js`.

In `instance` param you have the ViewModel that you are activating so a possible solution could be to override the `updateDocumentTilte` function in `shell.js` or `main.js` and use the `instance` to get the values that you want. For example you could do something like this (make sure you have the `app` and the `router` instance):

```
 router.updateDocumentTitle = function (instance, instruction) {
            if (instance.setTitle)
                document.title = instance.setTitle();
            else if (instruction.config.title) {
                if (app.title) {
                    document.title = instruction.config.title + " | " + app.title;
                } else {
                    document.title = instruction.config.title;
                }
            } else if (app.title) {
                document.title = app.title;
            }
        };
```

In this code we check if the instance (the current ViewModel) contains a method `setTitle`, if it does then we get the title calling the function. Then in our viewmodel we can have something like:

```
define(function () {

var id;
var vm = {
    activate: function (param) {
        id = param;
        return true;
    },
    setTitle: function () {
        return 'My new Title ' + id;  //Or whatever you want to return
    }
};

return vm;
});
```

If your viewmodel does not contain this method, then it should fall to the current behaviour.

Comment: Great, that works :) I just had to modify your code a little:

Comment: Cool! Yep, I noticed before.. I added an else after the first if. Glad it worked!

Comment: `updateDocumentTitle` doesn't fire when changing the value of the observable inside it. I'm using the observable because my title is dependent on some information I get after an ajax call.

Comment: In which time of the composition do you do the ajax call? On activate? setTitle should be called after activate callback.

Comment: Make sure you override the function BEFORE returning the viewmodel in shell. Otherwise it won't work. Good answer btw!

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I achieved it:

```
    activate: function (product, context) {
        // Update the title
        router.activeInstruction().config.title = "Buy " + product;
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

It works, but I don't know if that's the ***approved*** method.

Comment: This seems a lot simpler than the accepted answer, and doesn't involve overwriting any Durandal functions

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use observables for this, because the data that the title is derived from is loaded by AJAX in the `activate` method.

So I put this in my application bootstrap code:

```
var originalRouterUpdateDocumentTitle = router.updateDocumentTitle;
router.updateDocumentTitle = function (instance, instruction) {
    if (ko.isObservable(instance.documentTitle)) {
        instruction.config.title = instance.documentTitle;
    }
    return originalRouterUpdateDocumentTitle(instance, instruction);
};
```

If the view model has an observable named `documentTitle`, it is copied to the `instruction.config.title`.  This is then bound to the actual `document.title` by Durandal (using a subscription), so that whenever the value of the `documentTitle` observable changes, the `document.title` changes.  The `documentTitle` observable could be a plain observable or a computed observable.

This approach also delegates most of the work to the actual `router.updateDocumentTitle()` method, by intercepting and modifying the `instruction` value based on `instance`, and then calling through to `originalRouterUpdateDocumentTitle`.

This works with Durandal 2.1.0.